# Rails I18n: datetime format inside translated string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-1.9.3, rails-i18n

I am a bit confused as to how I can specify what datetime format (or specifically date format in this case) should be used to translate dates inside a localized string.

So far, I have this:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
    date:
        formats:
            month: '%B %Y'
    texts:
        only_showing_between: "Only showing events between %{from} and %{to}."


# app/views/mymodel/index.html.erb
<%= content_tag :p, t('texts.only_showing_between', :format => :month, :from => @listing[:from], :to => @listing[:to]), :class => 'text-muted' %>
```

But it doesn't seem to apply the custom format. Any helpful pointers would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a cleaner way but this should work:

```
t('texts.only_showing_between', :from => l(@listing[:from], :format => :month), :to => l(@listing[:to], :format => :month))
```

Take a look the [localize method](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.0.0/AbstractController/Translation#localize-instance_method)

Remember: you must change the "date" key for "time" (for example) in your .yml file if `@listing[:from]` and `@listing[:to]` are not date objects